# Alignment changes for views when app is back after taking a picture

Tags: java, android

Cases are

1. Screen Rotation is not allowed on device (Rotation is locked)
2. During Image capture by camera, camera still can rotate (I don't know why Android is allowing that)
3. When I click back after capturing image but not on tick button (which appears after taking picture).
4. I have RTL language selected Alignment is back to English but text is still of RTL language:
   [image: Alignment is back to English but text is still of RTL language]
5. onCreateView I select the locale again but it is not working.
6. On Emulator it is working fine.

Comment: `setLayoutDirectionn` according to locale also

Comment: your 1st point not clearly describe please add code and screenshot also.